# How would I create an HTML page where multiple versions of a div could be shown depending on appeneded URL parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is showing different messages based on something like "?HELLO" being appended onto the URL of a page. For the purpose of this question, the page content could be something as simple as this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Content</title>
<style>
#container {width:100%height:100px;background:#000;}
#container div {text-align:center;color:pink;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="hello">How are you</div>
<div id="goodbye">See you later</div>
<div id="whoAreYou">Get Out</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also I would be interested in knowing how to do this using a single div and getting element by ID. I'm not sure which would work better for me in the end. I might want to add other elements based on the parameters like links or images. A client of mine has an eCommerce site and is considering implementing something like this for customers who land on the site with promocodes which will look like "?SourceCode=HELLO" but I'm assuming a string is a string.

Here is a fiddle although i don't think it will help for testing the URL [jsfiddle.net/stormbloom/caqfxx46](http://jsfiddle.net/stormbloom/caqfxx46)

Comment: You should provide some actual JS / JQuery code to show that you've put some effort into solving the problem yourself. Then you can ask how to solve a specific problem if you get stuck.

Comment: Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/stormbloom/caqfxx46/ This mostly a combination of Phillips answer and my best guessing

Answer (score 1):

***Updated***

I'm updating the answer to include implementation. It seems that you really want to just change the messaging based on the value of the query string. It's best to then store your messages in a scalable fashion and then just change a single div out.

**Step 1** - Get the query parameter value

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var parameter = getParameterByName('SourceCode');
```

**Step 2** - Store Your Messages

```
var messages = {
    hello: "Hi",
    goodbye: "Goodbye",
    default: "Who are You?"
}
```

**Step 3** - Change Message Based on Value of Query

```
var changeMessage = function(queryValue) {
    var container = $('#container');
    container.html(messages[queryValue]);
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wf2x6yua/2/

Comment: Philip - My knowledge of JS is very novice. My best guess is to add something like this into the if statement $('#whoAreYou').hide(); $('#goodbye').hide(); $('#hello').show(); but this isn't working for me

Comment: case sensitive? HELLO vs hello

Comment: @Stormy I've updated my answer. If it's the correct one, please consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I can't get it to work. Here is a link to a webpage I'm trying this on http://josemayorquin.com/test2.html?SourceCode=hello

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based on @Phillip Chan 's answer and your jsfiddle.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

function setContainerByParam(parameter) {
    // hide all divs inside "container"
    $("#container > div").hide();
    // show divs, based on the given parameter
    if (parameter === "hello") {
        $("#hello").show();
    } else if (parameter === "goodbye") {
      $("#goodbye").show();
    } else if (parameter === "whoAreYou") {
        $("#goodbye").show();
    } else {
      $("#unknown").show();
    }
}

// try to get param "SourceCode" and set divs
var url_param = getParameterByName('SourceCode');
setContainerByParam(url_param);

// try to set divs by simulating different parameters
setTimeout(function(){ setContainerByParam('hello'); }, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){ setContainerByParam('goodbye'); }, 4000);
setTimeout(function(){ setContainerByParam('whoAreYou'); }, 6000);

});
```

```css
#container {width:100%height:100px;background:#000;}
#container div {text-align:center;color:pink;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="hello">How are you</div>
    <div id="goodbye">See you later</div>
    <div id="whoAreYou">Get Out</div>
    <div id="unknown">unknown parameter</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this on an actual web page but it doesn't work. Any ideas? http://josemayorquin.com/test.html?SourceCode=hello

Comment: You did not include the JQuery library `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` - for productiive use you should save the library on your server and include it from there, but for testing you can use this googleapis link.

Comment: I'm not sure why but I couldn't get this to work right with jQuery included. I did some more digging though and found this tutorial, which worked for me http://jennamolby.com/how-to-display-dynamic-content-on-a-page-using-url-parameters/

Comment: Right, my bad, you have to wrap everything in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` - but on the site you've linked that's described. The reason is, that you have to wait until the HTML part of your site has loaded before you can manipulate (show/hide) the elements.